# How to get Shipping method name and shipping price in onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I am trying to get shipping address title and shipping price for the selected shipping method in onepage checkout at the section 'Shipping methods' so that I can show those to my customer at the section "Payment methods" in onepage checkout which is just the next step after selecting 'shipping methods'.

Can someone help me to get shipping label and price in 'payment methods' section of onepage checkout.